# Count Multiple tables rows & display total it in label

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I have 12 tables total in MySQL & using vb.net. I have dashboard page in which I want to display how many rows in entire database have. So there will be count of all rows from different tables & it will be display total number of rows count in one label. Is it possible? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to just do a count.  A simple way is:

```
select ((select count(*) from table1) +
        (select count(*) from table2)) as TotalCount;
```

Comment: there is  syntax error with this query. I am using MYSQL. Can you please check once